# Android - Keep track of user touching a relativelayout

Tags: android, touch-event

I am using a relative layout with a background drawable as a custom button and using the onClick to send notification to a custom method. I am trying to make sure that I know exactly when the user is touching the relative view and be updated as soon as the user stops touching the relative view.

I am not sure how to be notified when a user no longer is touching the relativelayout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `OnTouchListener`, then just keep track of when the user put their finger down, and when they picked it back up. Take the difference of the two times to get the total time. To do this, declare the class variable

```
private Date downTime;
```

Then remove your old `onClickListener` (you add this logic below), add the `onTouchListener` to your view in `onCreate`:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        switch(e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                downTime = new Date();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                Date d = new Date();
                long clickDuration = d.getTime() - downTime.getTime();//this is the number of milliseconds the user took to click.
                //here you should also add your onClick logic.
                downTime = null;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh figured it out, thanks.. action up is working.. thanks to returning true! just more easier to use if else for this example. Thank you!